# Compare lines in a file having common last column but different in another column

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

How to compare consecutive lines from a text file where last column should be same? And at least one value in the 2nd last column must be mismatched.

1. Firstly, column 6 should be compared in the file, if matched
2. Then Compare column 4 for matched lines. In the column 4 all values should not be same at least one should be different. Here HSF1 and HIF1AN in line number 1,2,3.

**INPUT FILE**

```
chr10   102979  103832  HSF1        305
chr10   102979  103832  HIF1AN  1   305
chr10   102979  103832  HSF1        305
chr10   103124438   103124851   HSF1        471
chr10   103124438   103124851   EGLN1   2   471
chr10   103969896   103970503   HSF1        472
chr10   103969896   103970503   HSF1        472
chr10   39135037    39142175    HSF1        335
chr10   4191461 4191936 HSF1        309
chr10   4191461 4191936 HSF1        309
chr10   42423355    42424014    HSF1        336
```

**OUTPUT FILE**

```
chr10   102979  103832  HSF1        305
chr10   102979  103832  HIF1AN  1   305
chr10   102979  103832  HSF1        305
chr10   103124438   103124851   HSF1        471
chr10   103124438   103124851   EGLN1   2   471
```

Comment: What is your approach on this, e.g. what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the field separator here? It appears that some lines have 5 fields, some have 6. Unless it is tab-separated.

Comment: I see you are actually removing those lines having same column4&6; else print all those lines if another line found with same column6 but different in column4.

Comment: Maulinglawns: Thanks for your participation. I am trying but not able to make the logic with awk. I am a biologist. However, need it for my gradutation project.

Comment: Glenn Jackman: It is tab separated file. Yes, in few lines column 5 is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a tab-separated file, you can use GNU awk:

```
gawk -F'\t' 'NR == FNR {count[$6][$4]++; next} length(count[$6]) > 1' file file
```

```
chr10   102979  103832  HSF1        305
chr10   102979  103832  HIF1AN  1   305
chr10   102979  103832  HSF1        305
chr10   103124438   103124851   HSF1        471
chr10   103124438   103124851   EGLN1   2   471
```

This passes through the file twice: the first time to count how many $4 values occur for each $6; the second time to output a record if there are more than 1 $4 values for that $6.

It could probably be done in a single pass, at the expense of complexity, memory usage and possibly the loss of the original ordering.

---

Same logic in perl

```
perl -Mautodie -e '
    open $f, "<", shift;
    while (<$f>) {
        @F = split /\t/;
        $c{ $F[5] }{ $F[3] }++;
    }
    # re-process the file
    seek $f, 0, 0;
    while (<$f>) {
        @F = split /\t/;
        print if scalar keys %{ $c{$F[5]} } > 1;
    }
' file
```

Comment: gawk: NR == FNR {count[$6][$4]++; next} length(count[$6]) > 1
gawk:                     ^ syntax error

Comment: Am getting syntax error before [$4]

Comment: what version do you have? `gawk --version`

Comment: GAWK version is GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: hmm, I have version 4.1.3 -- I don't know when multi-dimensional arrays were added. If you can't upgrade, you might have to use perl. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: **suggestion**: you can use `$NF` in `count[$NF][$4]++`  instead and `length(count[$NF]) `, then you can remove the `-F'\t'` if we don't know what is the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line, store the line in a buffer if the last column has the same value as all the other lines in the buffer, otherwise process the buffer and empty it.

Processing the buffer means trying to find at least one pair of consecutive lines that don't share the 4th column's value and printing the buffer if successful.

I stored the exact lines in the buffer together with the individual columns for nicer output and easier access to the values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub process {
    my (@rows) = @_;
    my $different;
    for my $i (1 .. $#rows) {
        $different = 1, last if $rows[ $i - 1 ][4] ne $rows[$i][4];
    }
    print map "$_->[0]\n", @rows if $different;
}

my @buffer;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = split;
    if (! @buffer || $buffer[0][-1] == $columns[-1]) {
        push @buffer, [$_, @columns];
    } else {
        process(@buffer);
        @buffer = [$_, split];
    }
}
process(@buffer);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code. Being biologist not able to understand much.
Please explain !@buffer in the code?

Please add one more criteria in the code. I would highly appreciate.
Criteria: 1. Firstly, column 6 should be compared in the file, if matched
Modified Criteria: 2. Then Compare column 4 for matched lines. In the column 4 all values should not be same at least one HSF1 must be there. Here HSF1 and HIF1AN in line number 1,2,3.

Comment: `!` is the negation operator, so `! @buffer` is true when the array @buffer is empty.

Comment: To compare other columns, just use the same trick as I used to check there are different values in column 4, `$rows[ $i - 1 ] == $rows[$i]` must be true for all `$i`. Checking that column 4 has at least two different values is already implemented, so just add a test that it contains the needed value somewhere.

Comment: @ choroba: Thank you for your help. I try to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for supporting me. I really appreciate your help. The script is working as the table I want. Thanks again.

Comment: "Thank you" on StackExchange = upvote/accept.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh You really should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/353652) one of the answers if it helped you. That's a way of marking the question as solved, as well as rewarding in some way the people who spent their time working on your problems.